# Remove table column based on user group membership

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, razor

So technically what I have is working but it is **EXTREMELY** slow.

In a nutshell I am querying a database for data, then creating a viewmodel containing that data paired with an object containing user AD data.

Here is my ViewModel:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{

     public List<Submission> submissionList { get; set; }
     public LoggedInUser User
     {
         get
         {
             return new LoggedInUser();
         }
     }
}

public class Submission
{
    //... All the things ...
}
```

`LoggedInUser` is a helper class that I have that contain several different ad attributes, but for this matter I am looking at a bool value called `isAdmin`. If is admin is `True` I am wanting a specific column to be displayed.

This is how I am doing it via Razor/Html.

```
<table class="datatable table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            //. . . Column Headers . . .

            @if(Model.User.isAdmin)
            { 
                <th />
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.submissionList )
        {                 
            <tr id="@item.ID">
                //. . . Column Content . . .

                @if(Model.User.isAdmin)
                { 
                    <td>
                        <div id="approvalBtn-@item.ID">
                                <a href="#" onclick="quickApprove(@item.ID)">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success fa-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Submit for approval!"></i>
                                </a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I remove the checks for the `isAdmin`, the information displays MUCH faster. Going from 5 minutes down to roughly 10 seconds.

Is there possibly a better implementation with javascript?

Comment: Please note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you instantiate your `SearchViewModel` class? If you do it directly, you should create a specific property named `isAdmin` and set its value on instantiate, like this:

```
public class SearchViewModel
{
     public List<Submission> submissionList { get; set; }
     public bool isAdmin { get; set; }
}
```

And then..

```
var user = new LoggedInUser();
var viewModel = new SearchViewModel {
    submissionList = submissionList, //supose you already have this value
    isAdmin = user.isAdmin
};
```

Your razor would be modified to this:

```
<table class="datatable table table-bordered table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            //. . . Column Headers . . .

            @if(Model.isAdmin)
            { 
                <th />
            }
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var item in Model.submissionList )
        {                 
            <tr id="@item.ID">
                //. . . Column Content . . .

                @if(Model.isAdmin)
                { 
                    <td>
                        <div id="approvalBtn-@item.ID">
                                <a href="#" onclick="quickApprove(@item.ID)">
                                    <i class="fa fa-check text-success fa-lg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Submit for approval!"></i>
                                </a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                }
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: This is actually how I wound up implementing this. I just had not had a chance to update my question.